# Windows 7 loses Environment Variable after reboot

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I've got a PC with Windows 7, when i try to add an Environment Variable everything is just fine as long as i don't reboot. When I reboot the PC the Variable is gone.

I hope someone can help me.

-tmrbng

Comment: How do you add it?

Comment: I've added it using the Advanced system settings

Comment: Where has it gone from? Advanced System Settings? Environment for `cmd`/`PowerShell`? Do you have a `cmd` start-up file and if so what does it do? Try getting into Advanced System Settings from `explorer` started with Admin privileges.

Comment: @AFH After reboot it isn't showing up in the list of system variables at the Environment Variables. I've got to the Advanced System Settings over the System Information and yes i've got Admin privileges.